# access value in JSONArray C# UWP

Tags: c#, json, uwp

I want to extract the first value in a JSONArray as String. Somehow I have the wrong approach, I get an exception.

How can I improve this?

I think I reach the array fine via *`myJasonObject["entities"].toArray()`*, but when I try to do something like *`getString()["entity"]`* afterwards, it's marked as error by VS.

***I want to be able to store "dax" (the value of "entity"):***

```
Response{
  "query": "what about dax",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "StockPrice2",
    "score": 0.3969668
  },
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "StockPrice2",
      "score": 0.3969668
    },
    {
      "intent": "None",
      "score": 0.372112036
    },
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "dax",
      "type": "StockSymbol"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get "dax" using following:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
JArray entities = obj.GetValue("entities") as JArray;
var firstEntity = entities.FirstOrDefault() as JObject;
var entityPropertyValue = entity.GetValue("entity");
var daxString = entityPropertyValue.ToString();
```

Comment: if "entities" contained a second or third item in the array, how would you go about accessing them?

Comment: @PaulAlexander `JArray` has indexer property in which you can pass `key` or `index`, so you can directly access third object using `entities[2]`, or you can enumerate through the array, if you need to access each object inside array